# Nodejs json string shows as [object Object]

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, node.js

Front End

```
// js / jquery
var content = {
    info : 'this is info',
    extra : 'more info'
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/tosave',
    data: content
});
```

Node

```
// app.js
app.post('/tosave', function(req, res){
    fs.writeFile('/saved.txt', req.body, function(err, data){})
});
```

This saves to the file as `[object Object]`. I get the same result when I use `JSON.stringify()` on content before sending it through the ajax request. However, if I stringify it in node.js it successfully saves as `{"info":"this is the info","extra":"this is extra"}`.

My question is why this happens? Also, how would I go about converting it to a json string before the ajax request?

Comment: Surely the correct syntax for `writeFile` in your example would be: `fs.writeFile('/saved.txt', data, function(err){})`

Comment: Yea, I just edited my example, that wasn't the issue

Comment: Well, the default string representation of an object is `[object Object]`.

Comment: Is this a problem? If you want it as a string at the node end you can stringify it there. It seems like node is just recognising that it is a json string and decoding it for you on the way in.

Comment: I see, but how can I write the content to file without with actual data, instead of [object Object], so I actually see the data?

Comment: As you've said yourself, you can stringify it in node and get the string into the file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like both jquery and node are being very helpful here.

Jquery recognises that you are sending an object and automatically converts into a format that can be transported before it sends it.

Node recognises what you are sending and decodes it when it receives it, turning it back into an object.

Basically this means that you don't have to worry about the transport.

What's not to like about that?

Comment: This is technically incorrect; jQuery sends the object as POST data, not JSON. Node then converts the POST data it receives into an object.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to send text (e.g. that happens to look like correct JSON, but isn't), and don't want Node to see it as JSON and convert it into an object for you, you could try specifying:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/tosave',
    data: content,
    processData: false
});
```

This will cause the data to be sent with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which might possibly prevent Node from helpfully turning the data into a JSON object.

However I would recommend simply stringifying `req.body` before writing it to the file. `writeFile` doesn't do this for you because you can send a buffer instead of a string, I suppose.